# browser local storage, tied to the domain AND that only live as long as the browser window

Tags: html, browser, cross-browser

Does browser local storage with the following characteristics exists :

1. lives only as long as the browser window
2. is tied to the domain (JS code from other domains cannot access it), OR is erased when the page reloads with a URL from another domain
3. is stored only in RAM (not on the disk)
4. is not sent to the server (excludes cookies)

I beleive the answer is no, but I'd like to be surprised !

storing data in window.name comes close, but does not satisfy (2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you say sessionStorage, let see [what developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) says:

> The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage
>   object. sessionStorage is similar to localStorage, the only difference
>   is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data
>   stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A
>   page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives
>   over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window
>   will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how
>   session cookies work.

Then, there is an example too:

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

If you close the browser or change the domain, the sessionStorage item is erased.

Comment: Not exactly, If you open your web app and there you have a sessionStorage, then just cahnge the address bar to google.com. and then change the address bar again to your web app (e.g. `localhost:3000`) you can see that your sessionStorage still exists with the old data :(